# Javascript Date object keeps on returning the default date (Mon Jan 19 1970 19:18:18) when trying to convert unix time

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to use the date function to convert unix time that I am trying to convert to a certain format. The function successfully returns the date in the format requested, but the time is wrong. What am I missing here?

```
const date = (e) => { 
  const unixTime = 1642698000
  const format = {
    weekday: 'long',
    day: 'numeric', 
    month: "2-digit", 
    year: "numeric"
  }
  return(new Date (unixTime).toLocaleString('en-US', format))
}
```

Expected output (app.)

```
Tue Jan 18 2022 17:00:00
```

The output recieved

```
Mon Jan 19 1970 19:18:18 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

I tried following other exampled but I wasn't able to find any that would resolve this issue. I appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: JavaScript represents the Unix time stamp in milliseconds and not seconds.

Answer (score 3):

The [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) from Javascript accepts the number of **milliseconds** as timestamp, not unix time (number of seconds). So, to adjust that, is just multiply the unix time by 1000.

```js
const date = () => { 
  const unixTime = 1642698000 * 1000
  const format = {
    weekday: 'long',
    day: 'numeric', 
    month: "2-digit", 
    year: "numeric"
  }
  return(new Date (unixTime).toLocaleString('en-US', format))
}

console.log(date())
// logs Thursday, 01/20/2022
```

Comment: You should avoid answering questions that are already answered. An exception might be if the question is only partially a duplicate, but even then you should reference the duplicate questions for that part that is clearly a duplicate.